# Adding synx to XCode build phase

Tags: xcode

Since there is no easy way to create groups with real folders, I would like to have synx run on every build and sync my folders automatically.
I tried adding a build phase with the following script:

```
if which synx > /dev/null; then
    synx $SRCROOT/MyProject.xcodeproj
else
    echo "warning: synx is not installed"
fi
```

1. This code does not actually run for some reason
2. I don't know where to see the `echo` statements

Would love to get some help and understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING:**
I think that running `Synx` while building the project may cause you some issues. Since `Synx` change the folder structure and the Xcode project, you may have some problems with missing files!

**HOW TO DO IT:**

1. You have to be sure this script is under the `Build Phases` tab like this.

Btw thank you for the script :)

ps. a sugestion is to use `$PROJECT_FILE_PATH` instead of `$SRCROOT\something` so you avoid problems with relative/absolute path and is kind of a generic script.

[image: Build Phases]

2. To see the output for this command is available in the `Report Navigator`:

[image: Report Navigator]